# My application uses set schema and unqualified tables and I get confusing numbers from snapdyn_sql

Tags: db2, db2-luw

More of a finding, than a question, I'll add an answer in a minute.

The other day I stumbled upon an application that used several tables with the same name, but in different schemas. Example:

```
create table s1.parent (x int not null primary key);
create table s1.child (y int not null primary key, x int not null references s1.parent(x));

create table s2.parent (x int not null primary key);
create table s2.child (y int not null primary key, x int not null references s2.parent(x));
```

The application uses the pattern:

```
set schema s1;
select * from parent x join child y on ...
```

Despite that the question have been executed against several schemas, there is only one row in:

```
select num_executions, rows_read, stmt_text
from sysibmadm.snapdyn_sql
where stmt_text like '....%'
```

and the numbers appear to be cumulative for all schemas. Why is that, and how do I figure out metrics for the different schemas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more modern table function:

```
select EXECUTABLE_ID, STMT_TEXT, num_executions 
from TABLE(MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT('D', NULL, NULL, -2)) as T 
where stmt_text like 'select *%'"
```

returns individual metrics for the different schemas.

It still takes some further examination to find out what executable_id that belongs to each schema, so I much prefer qualified table names in queries over the `set schema` pattern.

If tables are not qualified by schema, the schema can be detected by:

```
select EXECUTABLE_ID, VALUE as SCHEMA, STMT_TEXT, num_executions
from TABLE(MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT('D', NULL, NULL, -2)) as T 
CROSS JOIN TABLE(COMPILATION_ENV(T.COMP_ENV_DESC)) S 
where stmt_text like 'select *%' 
  and name = 'SCHEMA'
```

More details on COMPILATION_ENV can be found in the answer provided by [Mark Barinstein](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/165222/mark-barinstein)

Answer (score 1):

It's an expected behavior. There is an internal Technote on this.

The [COMPILATION_ENV table function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0012549.html) helps with the `current schema` setting for each executable_id.